# What is circumradius $R$ of the great disnub dirhombidodecahedron, or Skilling's figure?

Tags: polygons, polyhedra, solid-geometry, constants

The vertices of a [*uniform polyhedron*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformPolyhedron.html) all lie on a sphere. Out of curiosity, I looked at the circumradius $R$ of the $75$ polyhedra (non-prism) in the list (which assumed side $a=1$).

For irrational $R$, almost all were roots of quadratics, quartics, and a few sextics that can factor over a square root: $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},\sqrt{11}$ (and combinations thereof).

But there were ***two*** exceptions. For the [*snub cube*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubCube.html) and the [*snub icosidodecadodecahedron*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubIcosidodecadodecahedron.html), it was over a cube root: $(19-3\sqrt{33})^{1/3}$ and $\big(\frac{27-3\sqrt{69}}{2}\big)^{1/3}$. Thus, their $R$ could be expressed by the *tribonacci constant* (root of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$) and *plastic constant* (root of $x^3-x-1=0$), respectively.

However, if the definition of a uniform polyhedron is relaxed slightly, there is a $76$th: the *[great disnub dirhombidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_disnub_dirhombidodecahedron)*, or Skilling's figure,

$\hskip2.5in$[image]

> **Q:** What is the circumradius $R$ of Skilling's figure with side $a=1$?

**P.S.** Essentially, I'm looking for a uniform polyhedron ([degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_star_polyhedron#Degenerate_cases) or not) such that the minimal polynomial of its $R$ factors over $\big(\frac{29-3\sqrt{93}}{2}\big)^{1/3}$ hence can be expressed in terms of the ***Narayana cow sequence constant*** (root of $x^3-x^2-1=0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The great disnub [has identical vertices and edges](http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/great_disnub_dirhombidodecahedron.html) as the [Great dirhombicosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_dirhombicosidodecahedron), which [has a circumradius](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatDirhombicosidodecahedron.html) of $\sqrt{2}/2$.

The Narayama cow sequence constant has a value of 0.325617..
The Pentagonal Prism Six Compound has diagonals of length 0.32492

Times 3 gets 0.97685  That's close to the lengths of the second and third longest diagonals in my [caltrop](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602770/any-other-caltrops/1647619).  If the the 4 tetrahedral points are removed, a lot of balancing might be possible, and the second longest diagonals would be quite close to that.  So, perhaps solve that figure for maximizing unit diagonals on 72 points and see if Narayana pops out.  I used this shape to get excruciatingly close to a new [solid of constant width](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/790393), maybe this cow constant could be the key to making it work.

[image: 72 points]

Comment: Thanks, Ed. However, the [cow sequence constant](https://oeis.org/A000930) is a root of $x^3-x^2-1=0$ hence $x \approx 1.4655$. Where did you get a value of  $y \approx 0.3256$?

Comment: From $\big(\frac{29-3\sqrt{93}}{2}\big)^{1/3}$.  Your question gave me an idea for a new question.

Comment: Ok. I have included an [addendum](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1667480/4781) below. If you ever come across a geometric solid involving a minimal polynomial with discriminant divisible by $31$, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I was going to say the same thing, that it has the same vertices and edges as the great dirhombicosidodecahedron, aka Miller's Monster, and thus has the same radius, $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.  I'll just add a quick explanation of why, since there's a simple way to see it.  Both polyhedra have square faces that pass through the centre of the model, so the circumradius of the polyhedron is just half the diagonal of a square with edge length 1, hence $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [wheels of similar triangles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WheelsOfPoweredTriangles/) where the sides are  powers of the square root of Narayana Cow Sequence constant.  I should look through my [canonical polyhedra](https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Canonical-Polyhedra) list.  As a side note, $t^6-4t^4-t^3+4t^2+2t-1$ works perfectly for the  Snub Dodecahedron.

[image: Narayana triangles]

Comment: Can such wheels also be found using $\sqrt{p}$ of $p^3-p-1=0$, where $p$ is the plastic constant?

Comment: Your $t$ is a root of $t^3-2t =\phi$. Will the tribonacci-like, $$x^3-x^2-x=\phi$$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555111/on-the-snub-cubes-t3-t2-t-1-and-snub-dodecahedrons-x3-x2-x-phi) and mentioned by John Sharp work as well for the snub dodecahedron? The relationship between the two is the simple $$x =\frac{\phi}t+1$$

Comment: Yes, the plastic constant makes dozens of wheels.  Also makes K19.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2390420/complete-graph-k-19-in-3-space-with-all-distances-at-powers-of-d/2513858

Answer (score 0):

(*This is an addendum to E. Pegg's answer and too long for a comment.*)

If there is a *[degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_star_polyhedron#Degenerate_cases)* uniform polyhedron with unit side and a circumradius $R$ that involves the Narayana cow sequence constant, then the discriminant of $R$'s minimal polynomial should be integrally divisible by $d=31$.

The assumption is as follows: Given fundamental discriminant $d$, there are exactly ***two*** imaginary quadratic fields with class number $h(-d)=3$ such that the *[Weber class polynomial](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1502)* $W$ has degree $3$. Furthermore, $W$ has unit coefficients. These are $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-23})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-31})$,

$$x^3-x-1 = 0,\quad x = P = \tfrac{\zeta_{48}\eta(\tau)}{\sqrt{2}\,\eta(2\tau)} = 1.3247\dots,\quad\tau = \tfrac{1+\sqrt{-23}}{2}$$

$$x^3-x^2-1 = 0,\quad x = N = \tfrac{\zeta_{48}\eta(\tau)}{\sqrt{2}\,\eta(2\tau)} = 1.4655\dots,\quad\tau = \tfrac{1+\sqrt{-31}}{2}$$

where $\zeta_{48}$ is the $48$th root of unity $e^{2\pi i/48}$, and $\eta(\tau)$ is the Dedekind eta function. Furthermore, though $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$ has $h(-d)=1$, we also have,

$$-x^3-x^2-x+1 = 0,\quad x = \frac{1}{T} = \tfrac{\zeta_{48}\eta(\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)}-1 = 0.5436\dots,\quad\tau = \tfrac{1+\sqrt{-11}}{2}$$

$P,N,T$ have *other* similarities. All are *Pisot numbers*, all are *limiting ratios* of well-known sequences, all appear in *pi formulas*, etc, etc. Since there is a geometric solid for $P$ and $T$, there might be a solid (degenerate, semi-regular, etc) for $N$ as well.

Comment: My idea -- build 3D points from the number field generated by the Narayana cow sequence constant.  Split the 3D points by their norm.  Do any of the resulting point sets have interesting polyhedra?  I've found a lot of pretty cases, but none that I'd say are particularly novel.

Comment: @EdPegg: Also, given the number field generated by $T$ and $P$, do you have an algorithm to recover the _snub cube_ and _snub Icosidodecadodecahedron_? Note that their circumradii $R_i$ are $$R_1 =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{T-3}{T-2}}$$ $$R_2 =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2P-1}{P-1}}$$ so it might be tricky.

Comment: I posted [polyhedra from number fields](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667644/polyhedra-from-number-fields).

Comment: Given $T$, the snub cube is a subset of $(±1, ±1/T, ±T)$ -- even permutations when an even number of plus signs and odd permutations when an odd number of plus signs.

Comment: @EdPegg: I just saw your post "polyhedral from number fields". Very nice generalization. :)