# Polyhedra from number fields

Tags: field-theory, computational-geometry, polyhedra

A [question on the disnub](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653621/what-is-circumradius-r-of-the-great-disnub-dirhombidodecahedron-or-skillings/) mentions

1. *golden* ($x^2-x-1=0$) gives the [*dodecahedron*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dodecahedron.html) + much more.
2. *tribonacci* ($x^3-x^2-x-1=0$) gives the [*snub cube*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubCube.html).
3. *plastic* ($x^3-x-1=0$) gives the [*snub icosidodecadodecahedron*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubIcosidodecadodecahedron.html).

All of these polyhedra can be built by generating 3D points in root $R$'s number with values $a + b R^c$ for integers $a$, $b$, $c$.  After that, pick points with the same norm and use those to make a polyhedron.

Is there a nice $R$ for generating the snub dodecahedron?

Is there an interesting polyhedron generated by the number field of the *Narayana cow sequence constant* (root of $x^3-x^2-1=0$)?  I found many pretty ones with octahedral symmetry, but none particularly noteworthy.

Take $R$ as the real root of ($x^3-6 x^2 + 4 x-2=0$).  This value deserves a name, since $(R^{24} -24) - e^{\pi \sqrt{163}} <10^{-14}$. That $R$ can generate this figure, which seems more interesting than polyhedra I made with Narayana's cow.

[image: moonshine polyhedron]

When generating from $a + b R^c$, the bounds on $a$, $b$, $c$ matter.  If all values are between -3 and 3, then we might say a particular polyhedron is easily generated by $R$.  The higher the bound, the greater the difficulty.  With a bound of 17, $$(0, 5, 17), (1, 12, 13), (3, 4, 17), (3, 7, 16), (5, 8, 15), (7, 11, 12), (8, 9, 13)$$ all have the same norm ($\sqrt{314}$), and can generate this figure:

[image: points at 314]

What $R$ values yield a particularly high number of vertices with a relatively low bound?  Are there $R$ values that make highly interesting polyhedra?

Comment: For the snub dodecahedron, from [this entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron#Cartesian_coordinates), will the number field generated by $R := x \approx 1.7155$ of  $-1 + 2 x + 4 x^2 - x^3 - 4 x^4 + x^6 = 0$ do the job?

Comment: You mention by "...these polyhedra can be built by generating 3D points in root $R$'s number with values $a+bR^c$..."  I was wondering:: What happens if we use the _complex root_ $R$ of $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$? Can we make polyhedra from _complex_ number fields?