# On the snub cube's $T^3-T^2-T=1$ and snub dodecahedron's $x^3-x^2-x=\phi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, golden-ratio, constants

John Sharp has this nice article, [*Beyond the Golden Section - the Golden tip of the iceberg*](http://archive.bridgesmathart.org/2000/bridges2000-87.pdf) where he recalls how certain constants appear in the,

**I.** [Snub cube:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_cube)

$$T^3-T^2-T=1\tag1$$

with *tribonacci constant* $T \approx 1.83929$.

**II.** [Snub dodecahedron:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron)

$$x^3-x^2-x=\phi\tag2$$

with *golden ratio* $\phi$ and  root $x \approx 1.94315$.

*Note*: Incidentally, these two solids are the only *Archimedean solids* that are *chiral* (with mirror images).

---

However, in the Wikipedia for the snub dodecahedron, we find instead the equations,

$$y=z-\frac1{z}\tag3$$

$$z^3-2z = \phi\tag4$$

> **Q:** Where did Sharp get the "tribonacci-like" equation $(2)$? And excluding the obvious relation $x^3-x^2-x = z^3-2z$, how is it related to $(3)$ or $(4)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a related discussion in this recent [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/288220/12905), it seems Sharp got the tribonacci-like equation for the snub dodecahedron from **Appendix A** of [*"Closed-Form Expressions for Uniform Polyhedra and Their Duals"*](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Peter_Messer/publication/220453459_Closed-Form_Expressions_for_Uniform_Polyhedra_and_Their_Duals/links/540479e00cf2c48563b095ee/Closed-Form-Expressions-for-Uniform-Polyhedra-and-Their-Duals.pdf) by Peter Messer.

**I.** It is known that circumradius $R$ for a [snub cube](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubCube.html) of unit edge length is given by

$$R = \frac12\sqrt{\frac{3-T}{2-T}}=1.34371\dots$$

where $T$ is the real root of,

$$T^3-T^2-T=1\tag1$$

**II.** On a hunch, after some experimentation, I found that for the [snub dodecahedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubDodecahedron.html), one just uses ***the same formula***

$$R = \frac12\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{2-x}}=2.15584\dots$$

where $x$ is the real root of,

$$x^3-x^2-x=\phi\tag2$$

And given

$$z^3-2z = \phi\tag3$$

it turns out the relationship between Sharp's $(2)$ and Wikipedia's $(3)$ is simply,

$$x=\frac{\phi+z}z$$