# Omar Khayyam and the tribonacci constant

Tags: geometry, math-history, cubics, constants

While trying to find the tribonacci cousin of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638737/generalizing-odoms-construction-of-the-golden-ratio), I came across this nice short article [*A Geometric Problem of Omar Khayyam and its Cubic*](https://www.itp.kit.edu/~wl/EISpub/A256099.pdf) by Wolfdieter Lang. Given the figure,

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

The problem is to find the point $P$ on a circle with radius $R$ such that,

$$\frac{x}{R} = \frac{R-h}{h}$$

By the Pythagorean theorem, we have $R^2 =h^2+x^2$. Eliminating $R$, we then get,

$$x^3-2hx^2+2h^2x-2h^3=0$$

If $h=10$, then $x^3+200x=20x^2+2000$, the cubic mentioned in Khayyam's [MacTutor](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Khayyam.html) biography and this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/khayyams-work-on-cubic-equations).

---

However, if $h=1$, then,

$$x^3-2x^2+2x-2=0$$

which, if this [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayyam#Geometric_algebra) is to be believed, was also solved by Khayyam using a circle and a hyperbola,

$\hskip2.0in$[image]

Remarkably, this real root is $\displaystyle x= \frac1T+1$ with *tribonacci constant* $T$. So Khayyam was playing with one of the $n$-nacci ratios *before* Fibonacci.

> **Q:** This is the ***fourth*** geometric context I've seen where the tribonacci constant plays a role, after the [snub cube](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555111/on-the-snub-cubes-t3-t2-t-1-and-snub-dodecahedrons-x3-x2-x-phi), the [hard hexagon model](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HardHexagonEntropyConstant.html), and [this short note](https://oeis.org/A058265/a058265_2.pdf). *Are there other geometric contexts that the tribonacci constant appears in?*